# How to solve the error secp256k1-sys v0.4.2?

Tags: wasm, error

**I'm adding a pallet2 to pallet1's runtime cargo.toml then I'm getting this error.
Thanks in advance!!**

```
Compiling secp256k1-sys v0.4.2
error: the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by default, you may need to enable the "js" feature. For more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support
     --> /Users/pankajchaudhary/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.7/src/lib.rs:235:9
      |
  235 | /         compile_error!("the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by \
  236 | |                         default, you may need to enable the \"js\" feature. \
  237 | |                         For more information see: \
  238 | |                         https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support");
      | |________________________________________________________________________^

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
     --> /Users/pankajchaudhary/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.7/src/lib.rs:262:5
      |
  262 |     imp::getrandom_inner(dest)
      |     ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
  error: could not compile `getrandom` due to 2 previous errors
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
  The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

  warning: error: unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible with triple "wasm32-unknown-unknown"'
  warning: 1 error generated.
  warning: In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/secp256k1.c:12:
  warning: In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/assumptions.h:12:
  warning: In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/util.h:16:
  warning: wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:4:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
  warning: extern const unsigned char WASM32_INT_SIZE = sizeof(int);
  warning:                            ^
  warning: wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:5:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
  warning: extern const unsigned char WASM32_INT_ALIGN = alignof(int);
  warning:                            ^
  warning: wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:7:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
  warning: extern const unsigned char WASM32_UNSIGNED_INT_SIZE = sizeof(unsigned int);
  warning:                            ^
  warning: wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:8:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
  warning: extern const unsigned char WASM32_UNSIGNED_INT_ALIGN = alignof(unsigned int);
  warning:                            ^
  warning: wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:10:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
  warning: extern const unsigned char WASM32_SIZE_T_SIZE = sizeof(size_t);
  warning:                            ^
  warning: wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:11:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
  warning: extern const unsigned char WASM32_SIZE_T_ALIGN = alignof(size_t);
  warning:                            ^
  warning: wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:13:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
  warning: extern const unsigned char WASM32_UNSIGNED_CHAR_SIZE = sizeof(unsigned char);
  warning:                            ^
  warning: wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:14:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
  warning: extern const unsigned char WASM32_UNSIGNED_CHAR_ALIGN = alignof(unsigned char);
  warning:                            ^
  warning: wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:16:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
  warning: extern const unsigned char WASM32_PTR_SIZE = sizeof(void*);
  warning:                            ^
  warning: wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:17:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
  warning: extern const unsigned char WASM32_PTR_ALIGN = alignof(void*);
  warning:                            ^
  warning: In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/secp256k1.c:20:
  warning: depend/secp256k1/src/ecdsa_impl.h:312:12: warning: use of bitwise '&' with boolean operands [-Wbitwise-instead-of-logical]
  warning:     return !rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scalar_is_zero(sigr) & !rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scalar_is_zero(sigs);
  warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  warning:                                                       &&
  warning: depend/secp256k1/src/ecdsa_impl.h:312:12: note: cast one or both operands to int to silence this warning
  warning: In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/secp256k1.c:17:
  warning: In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/ecmult_impl.h:16:
  warning: In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/ecmult.h:12:
  warning: depend/secp256k1/src/scratch.h:24:38: warning: unused function 'rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch_create' [-Wunused-function]
  warning: static rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch* rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch_create(const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_callback* error_callback, size_t max_size);
  warning:                                      ^
  warning: depend/secp256k1/src/scratch.h:26:13: warning: unused function 'rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch_destroy' [-Wunused-function]
  warning: static void rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch_destroy(const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_callback* error_callback, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch* scratch);
  warning:             ^
  warning: In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/secp256k1.c:17:
  warning: depend/secp256k1/src/ecmult_impl.h:1035:12: warning: unused function 'rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_multi_var' [-Wunused-function]
  warning: static int rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_multi_var(const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_callback* error_callback, const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_context *ctx, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch *scratch, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_gej *r, const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scalar *inp_g_sc, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_multi_callback cb, void *cbdata, size_t n) {
  warning:            ^
  warning: depend/secp256k1/src/ecmult_impl.h:621:12: warning: unused function 'rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_strauss_batch_single' [-Wunused-function]
  warning: static int rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_strauss_batch_single(const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_callback* error_callback, const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_context *actx, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch *scratch, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_gej *r, const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scalar *inp_g_sc, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_multi_callback cb, void *cbdata, size_t n) {
  warning:            ^
  warning: depend/secp256k1/src/ecmult_impl.h:863:15: warning: unused function 'rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_pippenger_scratch_size' [-Wunused-function]
  warning: static size_t rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_pippenger_scratch_size(size_t n_points, int bucket_window) {
  warning:               ^
  warning: depend/secp256k1/src/ecmult_impl.h:944:12: warning: unused function 'rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_pippenger_batch_single' [-Wunused-function]
  warning: static int rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_pippenger_batch_single(const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_callback* error_callback, const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_context *actx, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch *scratch, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_gej *r, const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scalar *inp_g_sc, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_multi_callback cb, void *cbdata, size_t n) {
  warning:            ^
  warning: error: unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible with triple "wasm32-unknown-unknown"'
  warning: 17 warnings and 1 error generated.

  error: failed to run custom build command for `secp256k1-sys v0.4.2`

  Caused by:
    process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/pankajchaudhary/Desktop/hero/target/release/wbuild/hero-runtime/target/release/build/secp256k1-sys-b827f0c0aca6da27/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
    --- stdout
    TARGET = Some("wasm32-unknown-unknown")
    OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
    HOST = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
    CC_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
    CC_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
    TARGET_CC = None
    CC = None
    CFLAGS_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
    CFLAGS_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
    TARGET_CFLAGS = None
    CFLAGS = None
    CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
    DEBUG = Some("false")
    CC_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
    CC_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
    TARGET_CC = None
    CC = None
    CFLAGS_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
    CFLAGS_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
    TARGET_CFLAGS = None
    CFLAGS = None
    CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
    running: "clang" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/include" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/src" "-I" "wasm-sysroot" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-DSECP256K1_API=" "-DENABLE_MODULE_ECDH=1" "-DENABLE_MODULE_SCHNORRSIG=1" "-DENABLE_MODULE_EXTRAKEYS=1" "-DUSE_NUM_NONE=1" "-DUSE_FIELD_INV_BUILTIN=1" "-DUSE_SCALAR_INV_BUILTIN=1" "-DECMULT_GEN_PREC_BITS=4" "-DECMULT_WINDOW_SIZE=15" "-DUSE_EXTERNAL_DEFAULT_CALLBACKS=1" "-DENABLE_MODULE_RECOVERY=1" "-o" "/Users/pankajchaudhary/Desktop/hero/target/release/wbuild/hero-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/build/secp256k1-sys-a050440d4b849ccc/out/depend/secp256k1/contrib/lax_der_parsing.o" "-c" "depend/secp256k1/contrib/lax_der_parsing.c"
    running: "clang" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/include" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/src" "-I" "wasm-sysroot" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-DSECP256K1_API=" "-DENABLE_MODULE_ECDH=1" "-DENABLE_MODULE_SCHNORRSIG=1" "-DENABLE_MODULE_EXTRAKEYS=1" "-DUSE_NUM_NONE=1" "-DUSE_FIELD_INV_BUILTIN=1" "-DUSE_SCALAR_INV_BUILTIN=1" "-DECMULT_GEN_PREC_BITS=4" "-DECMULT_WINDOW_SIZE=15" "-DUSE_EXTERNAL_DEFAULT_CALLBACKS=1" "-DENABLE_MODULE_RECOVERY=1" "-o" "/Users/pankajchaudhary/Desktop/hero/target/release/wbuild/hero-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/build/secp256k1-sys-a050440d4b849ccc/out/depend/secp256k1/src/secp256k1.o" "-c" "depend/secp256k1/src/secp256k1.c"
    cargo:warning=error: unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible with triple "wasm32-unknown-unknown"'
    cargo:warning=1 error generated.
    exit status: 1
    cargo:warning=In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/secp256k1.c:12:
    cargo:warning=In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/assumptions.h:12:
    cargo:warning=In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/util.h:16:
    cargo:warning=wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:4:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    cargo:warning=extern const unsigned char WASM32_INT_SIZE = sizeof(int);
    cargo:warning=                           ^
    cargo:warning=wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:5:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    cargo:warning=extern const unsigned char WASM32_INT_ALIGN = alignof(int);
    cargo:warning=                           ^
    cargo:warning=wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:7:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    cargo:warning=extern const unsigned char WASM32_UNSIGNED_INT_SIZE = sizeof(unsigned int);
    cargo:warning=                           ^
    cargo:warning=wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:8:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    cargo:warning=extern const unsigned char WASM32_UNSIGNED_INT_ALIGN = alignof(unsigned int);
    cargo:warning=                           ^
    cargo:warning=wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:10:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    cargo:warning=extern const unsigned char WASM32_SIZE_T_SIZE = sizeof(size_t);
    cargo:warning=                           ^
    cargo:warning=wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:11:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    cargo:warning=extern const unsigned char WASM32_SIZE_T_ALIGN = alignof(size_t);
    cargo:warning=                           ^
    cargo:warning=wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:13:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    cargo:warning=extern const unsigned char WASM32_UNSIGNED_CHAR_SIZE = sizeof(unsigned char);
    cargo:warning=                           ^
    cargo:warning=wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:14:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    cargo:warning=extern const unsigned char WASM32_UNSIGNED_CHAR_ALIGN = alignof(unsigned char);
    cargo:warning=                           ^
    cargo:warning=wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:16:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    cargo:warning=extern const unsigned char WASM32_PTR_SIZE = sizeof(void*);
    cargo:warning=                           ^
    cargo:warning=wasm-sysroot/stdio.h:17:28: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    cargo:warning=extern const unsigned char WASM32_PTR_ALIGN = alignof(void*);
    cargo:warning=                           ^
    cargo:warning=In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/secp256k1.c:20:
    cargo:warning=depend/secp256k1/src/ecdsa_impl.h:312:12: warning: use of bitwise '&' with boolean operands [-Wbitwise-instead-of-logical]
    cargo:warning=    return !rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scalar_is_zero(sigr) & !rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scalar_is_zero(sigs);
    cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    cargo:warning=                                                      &&
    cargo:warning=depend/secp256k1/src/ecdsa_impl.h:312:12: note: cast one or both operands to int to silence this warning
    cargo:warning=In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/secp256k1.c:17:
    cargo:warning=In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/ecmult_impl.h:16:
    cargo:warning=In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/ecmult.h:12:
    cargo:warning=depend/secp256k1/src/scratch.h:24:38: warning: unused function 'rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch_create' [-Wunused-function]
    cargo:warning=static rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch* rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch_create(const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_callback* error_callback, size_t max_size);
    cargo:warning=                                     ^
    cargo:warning=depend/secp256k1/src/scratch.h:26:13: warning: unused function 'rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch_destroy' [-Wunused-function]
    cargo:warning=static void rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch_destroy(const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_callback* error_callback, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch* scratch);
    cargo:warning=            ^
    cargo:warning=In file included from depend/secp256k1/src/secp256k1.c:17:
    cargo:warning=depend/secp256k1/src/ecmult_impl.h:1035:12: warning: unused function 'rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_multi_var' [-Wunused-function]
    cargo:warning=static int rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_multi_var(const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_callback* error_callback, const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_context *ctx, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch *scratch, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_gej *r, const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scalar *inp_g_sc, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_multi_callback cb, void *cbdata, size_t n) {
    cargo:warning=           ^
    cargo:warning=depend/secp256k1/src/ecmult_impl.h:621:12: warning: unused function 'rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_strauss_batch_single' [-Wunused-function]
    cargo:warning=static int rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_strauss_batch_single(const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_callback* error_callback, const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_context *actx, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch *scratch, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_gej *r, const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scalar *inp_g_sc, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_multi_callback cb, void *cbdata, size_t n) {
    cargo:warning=           ^
    cargo:warning=depend/secp256k1/src/ecmult_impl.h:863:15: warning: unused function 'rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_pippenger_scratch_size' [-Wunused-function]
    cargo:warning=static size_t rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_pippenger_scratch_size(size_t n_points, int bucket_window) {
    cargo:warning=              ^
    cargo:warning=depend/secp256k1/src/ecmult_impl.h:944:12: warning: unused function 'rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_pippenger_batch_single' [-Wunused-function]
    cargo:warning=static int rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_pippenger_batch_single(const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_callback* error_callback, const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_context *actx, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scratch *scratch, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_gej *r, const rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_scalar *inp_g_sc, rustsecp256k1_v0_4_1_ecmult_multi_callback cb, void *cbdata, size_t n) {
    cargo:warning=           ^
    cargo:warning=error: unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible with triple "wasm32-unknown-unknown"'
    cargo:warning=17 warnings and 1 error generated.
    exit status: 1

    --- stderr


    error occurred: Command "clang" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/include" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/src" "-I" "wasm-sysroot" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-DSECP256K1_API=" "-DENABLE_MODULE_ECDH=1" "-DENABLE_MODULE_SCHNORRSIG=1" "-DENABLE_MODULE_EXTRAKEYS=1" "-DUSE_NUM_NONE=1" "-DUSE_FIELD_INV_BUILTIN=1" "-DUSE_SCALAR_INV_BUILTIN=1" "-DECMULT_GEN_PREC_BITS=4" "-DECMULT_WINDOW_SIZE=15" "-DUSE_EXTERNAL_DEFAULT_CALLBACKS=1" "-DENABLE_MODULE_RECOVERY=1" "-o" "/Users/pankajchaudhary/Desktop/hero/target/release/wbuild/hero-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/build/secp256k1-sys-a050440d4b849ccc/out/depend/secp256k1/contrib/lax_der_parsing.o" "-c" "depend/secp256k1/contrib/lax_der_parsing.c" with args "clang" did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 1).
```

Comment: You will find a lot of other questions about this when searching for `imp` in the stackexchange. The problem is that you are trying to use std code in no-std.